# Configuration of Libinput on New Dell XPS 13 16.04 LTS

Tags: touchpad, gestures, libinput

I am a brand new Linux user and not a developer or anything, so my skills are still very, very basic. I have just purchased a Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu, and managed (probably) to install libinput to configure some multitouch gestures on my trackpad. These are the gestures that I would like to set up:

- 2-finger - natural scroll (swipe up/page down and vice versa)
- 2-finger click - menu option (like right click on a normal mouse)
- 3-finger left and right//up and down - change workspace in fullscreen (in ubuntu, this is currently accomplished only doing Ctrl+Alt+left/right/up/down. 
  Pinch in/pinch out - zoom in/zoom out
- 2-finger rotate clockwise/counterclockwise - rotate page or image (pdf, jpeg, etc.)
- Deactivate 3-finger swipe left/right - switch between previous and next webpages on your browser
- Deactivate 2-finger swipe left/right - switch between tabs on your browser.
  [for some reason these last two seem to be standard config on libinput]

I would also like to add the Option "Deactivate the touchpad when using the keyboard" or to find a way to regulate the sensitivity (as the touchpad seems to get activated involuntarily quite a lot).

When I enter the command `nano ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf`, this is what I get:

```
# Typically command will be xdotool, or wmctrl. See "man xdotool" for
# the many things you can action with that tool. Note that unfortunately
# xdotool does not work with native Wayland clients.
#
# Note the default is an "internal" command that uses wmctrl to switch
# workspaces and, unlike xdotool, works on both Xorg and Wayland (via
# XWayland). It also can be configured for vertical and horizontal
# switching over tabular workspaces, as per the example below. You can
# also add "-w" to the internal command to allow wrapping workspaces.

# Move to next workspace (works for GNOME/KDE/etc on Wayland and Xorg)
gesture swipe up        _internal ws_up
# gesture swipe up      xdotool key super+Page_Down

# Move to prev workspace (works for GNOME/KDE/etc on Wayland and Xorg)
gesture swipe down      _internal ws_down
# gesture swipe down    xdotool key super+Page_Up

# Browser go forward (works only for Xorg, and Xwayland clients)
gesture swipe left      xdotool key alt+Right

# Browser go back (works only for Xorg, and Xwayland clients)
gesture swipe right     xdotool key alt+Left

# NOTE: If you don't use "natural" scrolling direction for your touchpad
# then you may want to swap the above default left/right and up/down
# configurations.

# Optional extended swipe gestures, e.g. for browser tab navigation:
#
# Jump to next open browser tab
# gesture swipe right_up xdotool key control+Tab
```

Any suggestions on how to insert the commands? Do I need to write them directly on this file or elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Libinput-gestures following this [guide](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures). A simple workspace switch/overview with a 3 finger gesture swiping left/right (switch) or up/down (overview) can be set up with adding the following four lines:

```
    gesture swipe left      3 _internal ws_up
    gesture swipe right     3 _internal ws_down
    gesture swipe up        3 xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up
    gesture swipe down      3 xdotool key ctrl+alt+Down
```

I'll try to figure out how to enable your asked features. Then, hopefully, i will call you again. Don't forget to open the config file with root privileges:

```
    sudo nano ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf
```

After editing the file, stop and start the gesture service:

```
    libinput-gestures-setup stop
    libinput-gestures-setup start
```

Hope it works! ;)